# split semicolon separated values into multiple rows with other data javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

i have below data

```
result =

    [  
       {  
          "Id":"0012v00002InPVmAAN",
          "Test__c":"India; Africa; Mombasa",
          "Test1__c":"AFR; TFR; GFR"
       }
    ]
```

i am want to create a csv file out of the above data, basically splitting semicolon separated values (Test__c & Test1__c) into multiple rows with other data.

```
"Id,Test__c,Test1__c --> csv file column header
"0012v00002InPVmAAN","India","AFR"
"0012v00002InPVmAAN","Africa","TFR"
"0012v00002InPVmAAN","Mombasa","GFR"
```

JS -

```
this.data =result
downloadCSVFile() {
        let rowEnd = '\n';
        let csvString = '';
        // this set elminates the duplicates if have any duplicate keys
        let rowData = new Set();
        // getting keys from data
        this.data.forEach(function (record) {
            Object.keys(record).forEach(function (key) {
                rowData.add(key);
            });
        });
        // Array.from() method returns an Array object from any object with a length property or an iterable object.
        rowData = Array.from(rowData);
        // splitting using ','
        csvString += rowData.join(',');
        csvString += rowEnd;
        // main for loop to get the data based on key value
        for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            let colValue = 0;

            // validating keys in data
            for (let key in rowData) {
                if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    // Key value 
                    // Ex: Id, Name
                    let rowKey = rowData[key];
                    // add , after every value except the first.
                    if (colValue > 0) {
                        csvString += ',';
                    }
                    // If the column is undefined, it as blank in the CSV file.
                    let value = this.data[i][rowKey] === undefined ? '' : this.data[i][rowKey];
                    csvString += '"' + value + '"';
                    colValue++;
                }
            }
            csvString += rowEnd;
        }
```

I am trying the above code, it is printing (Test__c & Test1__c) values into single row.

How to create a csv file out of the above data, basically splitting semicolon separated values (Test__c & Test1__c) into multiple rows with other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version without downloadCSVFile function. I've replace this.data with `result`. If field names ('Id', 'Test__c', 'Test1__c') are fixed, then the second part of your code can be simplified:

```
const result = [
  {
    Id: "0012v00002InPVmAAN",
    Test__c: "India; Africa; Mombasa",
    Test1__c: "AFR; TFR; GFR"
  }
];

result.map(item => {});

let rowEnd = "\n";
let csvString = "";
// this set elminates the duplicates if have any duplicate keys
let rowData = new Set();
// getting keys from data
result.forEach(function(record) {
  Object.keys(record).forEach(function(key) {
    rowData.add(key);
  });
});
// Array.from() method returns an Array object from any object with a length property or an iterable object.
rowData = Array.from(rowData);

// splitting using ','
csvString += rowData.join(",");
csvString += rowEnd;

const lines = [];

lines.push(rowData.join(","));

result
  .reduce((acc, { Id, Test__c, Test1__c }) => {
    const a = Test__c.split(";");
    const b = Test1__c.split(";");
    a.forEach((item, index) => {
      acc.push({ Id, Test__c: item, Test1__c: b[index] });
    });
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .forEach(item => {
    lines.push(rowData.map(key => item[key]).join(","));
  });

csvString = lines.join(rowEnd);

console.log(csvString);

// Id,Test__c,Test1__c
// 0012v00002InPVmAAN,India,AFR
// 0012v00002InPVmAAN, Africa, TFR
// 0012v00002InPVmAAN, Mombasa, GFR
```

Comment: And you can use `const a = Test__c.split(/;\s*/);` regex version of split to avoid extra spaces around values in csv...